# Spring @Async not working on an anonymous class

Tags: spring-scheduled, spring-async

I am using @Async tag inside a method in Anonymous class. Does Spring AOP support this:

```
  private void scheduleProcessing(final SomePojo somepojo) {
      taskScheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          @Async("myThreadPoolTaskExecutor")
          public void run() {
            // biz logic
          }
      }, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }
```

Comment: Apparently methods denoted with spring annotations like Async, Transactional etc should be called from outside the class (AOP Proxy). Here run will be called somewhere internally when the Thread starts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently methods denoted with spring annotations like @Async, @Transactional etc should be called from outside the class (AOP Proxy). Here run will be called somewhere internally when the Thread starts hence not applying the async-ness to the method.